# selenium unable to set input for a input box which becomes select box on focus

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a webpage where I have a text input box which on click turns to a select box. The select items are appearing from a table. ie, A table is used as select input instead of options tag
I am able to get the value of each table td using xpath. But I am unable to choose the option in select.

While clicking on the input it turn into select box in which I can navigate using up or down arrow keys too.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='not-tbl']/tbody/tr[1]/td").click()
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='not-tbl']/tbody/tr[1]/td").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Xpath of input box : `//*[@id="not_cat"]`
HTML of select :

```
<input id="not_cat" value="" readonly="" ct="ComboBox" k="" ks="" lid="notification_in_category-lb" op="false" st="" vt="true" dd="true" ic="6" vs="" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="urCoB2TxtDdl" onfocus="sapUrMapi_ComboBox_focusDdlb('notification_in_category',event);" onblur="sapUrMapi_ComboBox_blurDdlb('notification_in_category',event);" onkeydown="sapUrMapi_ComboBox_keydown('notification_in_category',event);" onkeypress="sapUrMapi_ComboBox_keypress('notification_in_category',event);" onselectstart="sapUrMapi_cancelEvent(event);" style="width:119;" noblur="false" ll="false">
```

How to add this table td value into the input. Manually doing sendkeys are not working. Once the input box is having focus, it becomes a select box.

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the select input?

Comment: This is an interesting case -- is there any way you can link to the page you are testing? This will allow me to test out different methods.

Comment: @GregBurghardt done

Comment: @Christine, Sorry it is an internal website which is accessible only from a company network

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the thing this input turns into? Is it a table? Can you please post that HTML?

Comment: And do you need to have Selenium choose an option from the "select box" or is putting a value directly in the text input acceptable?

Comment: Selenium need to choose an option.. i am not able to put a direct value.. i tried sendkeys...but it is not working

Comment: The table is pre existing.. but instead of options for select.. the table td becomes the options for this input field...

Comment: I can use arrow keys(up and down) to navigate between then options and enter to select the highlighted one...

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution by my own.

I did a click first then gave a delay so that the select gets populated. Then I used arrow keys.

```
browser.find_element_by_id("not_cat").click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_id("not_cat").send_keys(Keys.DOWN * 4)
```